# Incorrect Resut for a Definite Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Entering the command

```
Assuming[a > 1, 
 Integrate[(a x Sin[x])/(1 - 2 a Cos[x] + a^2), {x, 0, \[Pi]}]
]
```

produces
$\pi  \log (a+1)$

The correct answer is  $\pi  \log
   \left(\frac{1}{a}+1\right)$

Comment: I did not have time to wait for the `Integrate` result, but graphically comparing the `NIntegrate` results with your two expressions appears to agree with you. Interestingly, Rubi quickly returns a more complex expression with Logs and PolyLogs that appears numerically equivalent to the `Integrate` result, and which `FullSimplify` reduces to the same result you report from `Integrate` when $a>1$ is given as assumption.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question here.  Problems with the software should be reported to WRI.

Comment: Let `indef = Assuming[a > 1, Integrate[(a x Sin[x])/(1-2 a Cos[x]+a^2), x] // FullSimplify]` then `(Limit[indef, x -> Pi] - Limit[indef, x -> 0]) // FullSimplify[#, a > 1]&` evaluates to `Pi*Log[1 + 1/a]`

Comment: The three lines, `Integrate[(a x Sin[x])/(1 - 2 a Cos[x] + a^2)/.a->1, {x, 0, \[Pi]}]`; 
`Integrate[D[(a x Sin[x])/(1 - 2 a Cos[x] + a^2),a], {x, 0, \[Pi]},Assumptions->a>1]`;
`%%+Integrate[%,{a,1,a},Assumptions->a>1]//Simplify` give the correct answer.